# using tabbed divs in ASP.net using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I want to make a tabbed divs in asp.net. These divs should be made visible using Jquery scroll effect.

Sort of like this,[Here](http://www.co5051.co.cc/pageDesign/TabbedDivs.htm)

but i want to use Jquery.

Here is my div

```
<div class="prodreview">

//this will contain a form that will allow the user to review a product
</div>


<div class="prodDesc">

//this div will simple show product description
</desc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at jQueryUI tabs

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

In your example, something like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#prodreview">Product Review</a></li>
        <li><a href="#prodDesc">Product Description</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="prodreview">
        //this will contain a form that will allow the user to review a product
    </div>
    <div id="prodDesc">
        //this div will simple show product description
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
```